# Query speed optimalization (neo4j)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hello fellow programmers,

I'm new to graph databases and I was wondering whether my approach was optimal or there is room for improvement.

I have a tree-like structure that changes a lot and I need to store it in my graph database.

For example:

[image: this image]

I receive updates in this form:

```
{
   path="2/5/9/4" 
   value="example"
}
```

Currently, the leaves hold the values as they change over time, and ancestor nodes store the path:

```
merge (a:A {label: 2})-[:NEXT]->(b:B {label:5})
merge (b)-[:NEXT]->(c:C {label:9})
merge (c)-[:NEXT]->(d:D {label:4})

on create set d.values = ["example"]
on match set d.values = d.values + "example"
```

Is there a more sophisticated/efficient solution?

Comment: Does the length of the path vary, or is it always 4 deep? And are the labels always A, B, C, D ... etc?

Comment: Yes the length varies. some labels are fixed and some are dynamic.

The length is usually around 10 but can reach as high as 25. 
Also there is 1/2 of labels static.

for example like this:
static/static/variable/static/variable/variable

Comment: You should strongly consider changing the confusing property name `label` to something else, as "label" is already used for a central concept in Neo4j -- a concept that actually needs to be used in your query. Here, I will assume the `label` property is renamed to `name`; and will use "label" in the standard way for neo4j. Does every path node have a unique (across the DB) combination of label and `name`? Or would it be possible for there to be, for example, multiple `(:B {name:5})` nodes in the DB?

Comment: I though neo4j would warn me that it's reserved keyword... Yes I can receive updates like this:
"a/5/c" and "a/5/d", so there will be two (:B {name: 5}).